# Struts 2 jQuery plugin in Pie Chart with json results

Tags: jquery, struts2, pie-chart, struts2-jquery

By using struts 2 jQuery plugin ....

I am trying to create a Pie Chart which gets its data dynamically via json.

Is it possible?

All samples mentioned in http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action and as long as I searched, are using `s:iterator` or static data.

Here is my codes:

```
   @Action(value = "json-chart-data", results = {
            @Result(name = "success", type = "json")
        })
      public String execute()
      {
        myData = new TreeMap<>();
        myData.put("a", 11);
        myData.put("b", 12);
        myData.put("b", 13);

        return SUCCESS;
      }
```

And the jsp:

```
<s:url id="chartDataUrl" action="json-chart-data" />
<sjc:chart  id="chartAjax"
        pie="true"
        pieLabel="true"
        cssStyle="width: 600px; height: 400px;" >
    <sjc:chartData      
        id="chartAjaxData"
        href="%{chartDataUrl}"
            //Here we need to set list,data and label!
    />
  </sjc:chart>
```

The tag is working and an json result is turned back. But the pie is not displayed.

The `cjc:chartData` has `list` , `data`, and `label` properties which needs to be set. I try different values but no luck.

Comment: Can you share the JSON response also how you are adding list,data and label, you have kept comments in that section so I cannot judge how you are using it?

Answer (score 1):

If think in your code, you need to have ***getter and setter*** for **myData** , and I also see that you have missed out `<type1,type2>` for your treeMap. These are things I pointed out based on code pasted by you, If you have them, then please paste proper code.